# smooth ac to measure with dc voltmeter

Tags: capacitor

I bought a couple of those 3 digit 0-30 volt dc voltmeters.  Im taking ac 0-24 volts (Lionel train transformer)  through a rectifier and measuring it with the led meter.  My problem is the meter never settles?

I was thinking a cap across the +- on the rectifier but since I dont have any caps in my part bins to experiment with I have to buy one so I need to know the value in advance.

Comment: Is that the kind with two wires (measures its own voltage) or three wires (power and separate input)?

Comment: Its a three wire.   I have it powered from a phone charger.  The negative is tied to the rectifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the meter has a separate signal input, it's difficult to know without having the input impedance of the meter, but let's assume it's maybe 100K ohms or thereabouts.

D1 and C1 (should be rated for 50V) filter the power to the meter. 
D2 (Schottky has a bit less drop, but you could use a regular diode too), C2 and R1
filter the signal to the meter. Again C2 should be rated for 50V (aluminum electrolytic).

A suitable part for the capacitors would be a Nichicon [UVZ1H471MHD](http://nichicon-us.com/english/products/pdfs/e-vz.pdf).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1xdkW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitor value is picked to have a time constant of about 1 second, which means that with 60Hz half-wave input, the ripple will be about +/-30mV or less than 1 count.

Edit: Since you've got it separately powered, you can ignore D1 and C1. See edit below following comment by @EMFields on scaling so higher voltages can be displayed. I've chosen to scale it by a number that approximates RMS reading, taking into account the "approximately 100K" input impedance of the meters you purchased (as shown in your link).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYiNpq.png)</sup>

If we assume the voltage drop across the Schottky is 250mV then for 24VAC RMS we'd get a reading of 24.2V, and for 10VAC RMS we'd get a reading of 9.9V- pretty good for a simple AC-DC converter.

Comment: Spehro, 24VRMS peaks out to about 34VDC, (but you know that :) so even with the Schottky in there his meter will overrange without some sort of divider on the front end.

Comment: @EMFields   You're right of course. I guess if we know the input impedance we could calculate a divider that would read equivalent to RMS

Comment: You're right, of course. :-) Maybe the OP will grace us with a link to the data sheet?

Comment: @danny117: Can you post a link to the voltmeter's data sheet, please? Or, in lieu of that, the manufacturer and model number?

Comment: Its a 0-30v i selected it based on the lionel transformer I use have max 24 volts.  http://pages.ebay.com/link/?nav=item.view&id=381059271561&alt=web

Comment: Look in description for data. runs on readily available phone charger.

Comment: Update caps arrived.  Thanks its working awesomely.  The divider is really close.  I'll put in a trim pot and get it exactly right.   About 50mv of ripple.